# How to change Widget Color in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to learn the basics of the Kivy package for Python GUI programming.  I've worked through the Pong Tutorial ([here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html)) and wanted to test my comprehension by changing the color of the pong ball every time it hit the wall.  It is not working - every time the ball hits the wall, I get a fault saying that there is not Color attribute.  What am I doing wrong?

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import  NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color
from random import randint

class PongBall(Widget):
    vel_x = NumericProperty(0)
    vel_y = NumericProperty(0)
    vel = ReferenceListProperty(vel_x,vel_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.vel) + self.pos

class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.vel = Vector(4,0).rotate(randint(0,360))

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        if(self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
            self.ball.vel_y *= -1
            self.ball.Color(1,0,0)

        if(self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.ball.vel_x *= -1
            self.ball.Color(0,1,0)


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
    game.serve_ball()
    Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
    return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

KV File:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 0, 0

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the following:

- Create a ListProperty to have the color information and make a binding in the .kv.
- The Color instruction must be before the Ellipse instruction:

```py
class PongBall(Widget):
    vel_x = NumericProperty(0)
    vel_y = NumericProperty(0)
    vel = ReferenceListProperty(vel_x,vel_y)
    color = ListProperty((1, 1, 1, 1)) # <---

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.vel) + self.pos

class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.vel = Vector(4,0).rotate(randint(0,360))

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        if(self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
            self.ball.vel_y *= -1
            self.ball.color = (1, 0, 0, 1) # <---

        if(self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.ball.vel_x *= -1
            self.ball.color = (0, 1, 0, 1) # <---
# ...
```

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color # <---
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
# ...
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks.  The one other thing I would emphasize is that I needed the color property above the ellipse property on the canvas.